# Sequentially run commands in bash script

Tags: bash, background, sequence, daemon

I need to run two commands sequentially in daemon mode (the commands will output the errors on stderr). The problem is that even I dump all the output in /dev/null, the second command (run_cmd2) cannot be invoked. Here is my script

```
#! /bin/bash
nohup ./run_cmd1 &> /dev/null &
nohup ./run_cmd2 &> /dev/null &
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to run those _sequentially_, why are you running those in the background?

Comment: Are you sure that those commands are only outputting on stderr?  If they output on stdout as well, it will stop the script.

Comment: `nohup sh -c './run_cmd1; run_cmd2' 2>/dev/null &`

Comment: I can dump everything in /dev/null, still doesn't work, `nohup ./run_cmd1 &> /dev/null &`

Comment: @tripleee, it doesn't work

Comment: @perigee you're saying that `run_cmd2` doesn't run? Where does `run_cmd1` come in?

Comment: @thatotherguy the run_cmd1 is running, it is a script.

Comment: @perigee Have you ever gotten `./run_cmd2` to run successfully in any way whatsoever?

Comment: @thatotherguy, the commands are tested separately, it works

Comment: @perigee when you tested tripleee's example above, did you add `./` to run_cmd2? Can you try it again without redirect stderr and see what kind of errors it outputs to nohup.out?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, I tested it with ./

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, I tested it with ./, and inside nohup.out, there is only errors output from cmd1, since it's daemon, cmd1 keeps running, these errors just for monitoring.

Comment: Does `run_cmd2` only work if `run_cmd1` is already running?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes,it works. Actually, two daemons communicate each other, if there is one daemon down, another just waiting for it online again

Answer (score -3):

How about using a file to communicate state?

run_cmd2 will wait until a file exists before running

when run_cmd1 is done, it will create the said file.

at the end of its run the run_cmd2 will delete the file, so run_cmd1 can run again

Or maybe they talk to each other using a port?

Or maybe a semaphore?

For more details: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html

Comment: -1 Massive over-engineering. Sequential execution is the default.

Comment: Sequential one is default, only problem is that the daemon output blocks the execution of the second command....

Comment: @tripleee: Please re-read the question. Although sequential is the default, perigee wants to make sequential calls of running processes in the background.